# detect if iPhone/iPad is password protected

Tags: javascript, iphone, cocoa, ipad

I am fairly sure that this would not be possible, but just want to check.

Is it possible to work out if a user has their iPhone/iPad password protection turned on.

We are working on an application that contains very sensitive corporate information, we would like to avoid having to ask the user their password every time they open the iPhone/iPad application, however this is a security issue that could be mitigated by ensuring that the user has their password protection turned on.

ie Users with password protection turned on are allowed to access the data without needing a password. Users without password protection are required to enter their password to access the data.

And yes I know this is not very user friendly but it is out of my control

Comment: Are you aware of [this bug](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/hardware/ubuntu-lucid-lynx-1004-can-read-your-iphones-secrets/8424 "Ubuntu Lucid Lynx 10.04 can read your iPhone's secrets")?

Comment: @SLaks Any app with private information should be using encryption on its own data anyway, so that bug is not as dangerous as it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to detect this programmatically from within an iPhone SDK-based application. If you need to, you should file an enhancement request with Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com .